# How to change the color of ActionBarToggle in android while using toolbar in android lollipop?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-5.0-lollipop

How to change the **color of ActionBarToggle**? 
I have searched through net but I did not found any specific answer.

Currently I am using   **android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity**

I have applied two method `setLogo` and `setIcon` but these are adding the image not replacing toggleBar.

Answer (score 0):

Altering the color of the navigation icon (i.e., the icon which switches between a burger icon and a back arrow icon) is actually a bit tricky, but can be achieved like so:

```
public void setNavigationIconColor(int color)
{
    ColorMatrix matrix = new ColorMatrix();
    matrix.setScale(Color.red(color) / 255f, Color.green(color) / 255f, Color.blue(color) / 255f, 1);
    ColorMatrixColorFilter filter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(matrix);
    mToolbar.getNavigationIcon().setColorFilter(filter);
}
```

This code assumes the `Toolbar` has already been configured, and that you are using a theme which normally displays the icon as white (`@style/DrawerStyleLight`)

Comment: I have implemented this method also, previously it was giving error and now also.  May be I am missing something to configure the TOOLBAR. Have you any suggestion on this.

Comment: There's no way I can answer this unless you post your code.